# separate outputs of "find" with a space in terminal

Tags: terminal, find

I am using `find` to find all folders which include more than 20 of a specific type (`.txt`) as below:

```
 find . -type f -iname '*.txt' -printf '%h\n'|sort|uniq -c | awk '$1 > 20'
```

The output looks like:

```
  44 ./fold9863
    202 ./fold689
    122 ./fold45
    202 ./fold2
```

with the numbers showing the number of the .txt files in each folder. Is there any way that I could use find to get the folder names without numbers (and without the leading `./`), but seperated by a space? like this:

```
fold9863 fold689 fold45 fold2
```

Comment: Try changing the awk part to `awk -v ORS=' ' '$1 > 20 { print $2 }'`. (untested)

Comment: When I try find . -type f -iname '*.txt' -printf '%h\n'|sort|uniq -c | awk -v ORS=' ' '$1 > 20 { print $2 }' , it doesn't give any outputs. @user414777

Comment: It may be because of your prompt. Add an `; echo` after the command. Or use a (unquoted) command substitution: `echo $(... | awk '$1 > 20 { print $2 })` which takes care of translating newlines to spaces. Just like your original example, all these will run into issues with filenames containing spaces or newlines.

Comment: Is there any way to remove ./ befor the name of folders? The output looks like ./fold9863 ./fold689 ./fold45 ./fold2 now @user414777

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following does print the folder names on one line delimited by a single space:

```
find . -type f -iname '*.txt' -printf '%h\n'|sort|uniq -c | \
  awk '$1 > 20 { sub("^[.]/","",$2); printf("%s ",$2) } END { printf("\n") }'
```

A caveat is that if the folder name contains spaces, probably something will go wrong when you use the list.  It is possible to quote the names:

```
find . -type f -iname '*.txt' -printf '%h\n'|sort|uniq -c | \
  awk '$1 > 20 { sub("^[.]/","",$2); printf("\"%s\" ",$2) } END { printf("\n") }'
```

An extra space is at the end of the line, but with extra code that could also be avoided.  One possibility:

```
find . -type f -iname '*.txt' -printf '%h\n'|sort|uniq -c | \
  awk '$1 > 20 {sub("^[.]/","",$2);printf("%s\"%s\"",X,$2);X=" "} END {printf("\n")}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `awk` expression with this one, which removes any leading `./` from the folder name

```
awk '$1 > 20 { sub("^\\./", "", $2); printf "%d\t%s\n", $1, $2 }'
```

To get the folder names in a line, rather than in a column, modify the `awk` again, this time to avoid printing the numbers

```
awk '$1 > 20 { sub("^\\./", "", $2); printf "%s ", $2 } END { printf "\n" }'
```